# Non SharePoint sites on SharePoint 2010 Online IIS

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-online

We need to expose a site to the internet and we already have an internet facing SharePoint 2010 site on Azure. Is it good practice to host the site which is non SharePoint on the same IIS as SharePoint? Is there anything that can go wrong with our SharePoint site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a recommended practice.

There are multiple reasons:

1. SharePoint assumes it's the only application on the system.  It is possible some activities could remove your other web site.  (In practice I have not seen this as an issue - but you can't count on that and need to plan accordingly).  As long as you are not using code on the back end to manage or manipulate other published web application, security settings, or accounts, it should not interfere with SharePoint.
2. You are introduces a potentially new security vulnerability to your SharePoint server. SharePoint has a lot of security controls and checks to protect your server from malicious access.  If your other web application is not engineered to the same degree you increase the risk of your server being compromised.

really you just need to do a Risk assessment to see if that makes the most sense.  You have to consider the financial impact of spinning up a new server (including support and maintenance) vs. re-using your currently deployed server.  You may get some die hard "don't do it" responses but the correct decision has to be made based on your business requirements, restrictions, and accepted risk.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer it has made my decision simpler.

Answer (score 0):

On one hand, there shouldn't be any technical problem with this. Just create another site running on a different port or host header. On the other hand, SharePoint is designed to scale up or down, allowing you to add or remove web servers from the farm. Clearly, this would cause issues with an app deployed to a single SharePoint WFE.